# Symfony 2.6.1 app only running in PROD enviroment

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-routing

I'm developping a Symfony 2 application (version 2.6.1) but I can only run it on PROD mode. When trying to access to the following URL :

```
http://localhost/lawAdmin/web/app_dev.php
```

I'm having the next error message:

> RouteNotFoundException in appDevUrlGenerator.php line 32: Unable to
>   generate a URL for the named route "_profiler" as such route does not
>   exist.

Both my routing.yml and routing_dev.yml files look the same:

```
law_admin:
    resource: "@LawAdminBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /
```

Running

```
app/console debug:router
```

returns:

```
 [router] Current routes
 Name          Method Scheme Host Path
 porfolio_show GET    ANY    ANY  /
 gallery_show  GET    ANY    ANY  /gallery/{galleryId}
```

I've also tried the following command just in case unsuccessfully:

```
php app/console cache:clear
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your routing dev to

```
_wdt:
    resource: "@WebProfilerBundle/Resources/config/routing/wdt.xml"
    prefix:   /_wdt

_profiler:
    resource: "@WebProfilerBundle/Resources/config/routing/profiler.xml"
    prefix:   /_profiler

_main:
    resource: routing.yml
```

This will load profiler and toolbar routes on dev environment, and load your own application routes from routing.yml file.

Comment: Thanks, quentinus95! It was just that! The thing that surprises me is that I expected that config file to be on my routing_def file by default. But it was empty...